# Can I execute Two different Classes from same jar file?

Tags: java, jar

I have a project where in one package I have made Server and in Second Package I made Client. It is working fine. I want to create a Jar file. Is it possible to run Client and Server Separately from same jar file?

I have used jar file where there is only one main and when I run jar file, it automatically runs that class. Now here I will be having 2 executable classes. I want to pack them in only one jar and then want to run both from that same jar file. Is it possible? Any Suggestions, links will be of great help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is, YES!

The longer answer is that you can specify the class in your command line as well as putting the .jar in the classpath.

Assume two classes

```
A.class 
B.class
```

jar them into a .jar file

```
jar cvf AB.jar A.class B.class
```

run either of them

```
java -classpath AB.jar A
java -classpath AB.jar B
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming both your Server and Client classes have `main` methods, you can execute them from the command line using the following:

`java -cp jarFile.jar package1.Server`

`java -cp jarFile.jar package2.Client`