# How to convert multiple class files to one jar file?

Tags: java, jar, applet

I have decompiled a jar file,

[image]

and made two classes from it. After that, I tried to make a new jar file with these two class files, using this code

```
jar cvf AB.jar WinRegistry.class StartPageChangeApplet.class
```

The file created without any errors. However, when I look at the source code on Java Decompiler, it says "Internel Error", means that I couldn't make the jar file properly.

[image]

Where am I doing doing wrong ?

Comment: What are you doing to execute that jar ?

Comment: You should really better explain what it does not work. Moreover, remember that if you use packages, you should add the complete path of each class.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309834/can-i-execute-two-different-classes-from-same-jar-file or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976514/multiple-runnable-classes-inside-jar-how-to-run-them

Comment: It probably means that your Java decompiler has a bug, or can't read class files generated with your compiler. To check that the jar is OK, execute a Java program which loads the classes in the jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please define "made two classes from it". Which java compiler (e.g. javac.exe) are you using? Did you just copy the source to a .class file without compiling maybe?

The java decompiler JAD actually displays source code, not class bytecode. Don't get confused by the title of the editor which is saying `WinRegistry.class`.

So you can't just save that as a `.class`. You need to save it as a `.java` and then compile it to `.class` using a java compiler:

```
javac WinRegistry.java StartPageChangeApplet.java
jar cf AB.jar WinRegistry.class StartPageChangeApplet.class
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I do. I just saved as class files.

Answer (score 1):

From Eclipse, you can do this way.. [image]